# A vector and matrix rows cosine similarity in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, cosine-similarity

In pytorch, I have multiple (scale of hundred thousand) 300 dim vectors (which I think I should upload in a matrix), I want to sort them by their cosine similarity with another vector and extract the top-1000. I want to avoid for loop as it is time consuming. I was looking for an efficient solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [torch.nn.functional.cosine_similarity](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.cosine_similarity) function for computing cosine similarity. And [torch.argsort](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.argsort) to extract top 1000.

Here is an example:

```
x = torch.rand(10000,300)
y = torch.rand(1,300)
dist = F.cosine_similarity(x,y)
index_sorted = torch.argsort(dist)
top_1000 = index_sorted[:1000]
```

Please note the shape of `y`, don't forget to reshape before calling similarity function. Also note that `argsort` simply returns the indexes of closest vectors. To access those vectors themselves, just write `x[top_1000]`, which will return a matrix shaped `(1000,300)`.